# Is there a test/lab environment for SonicWALL firewalls?

Tags: firewall

Does anyone know if there is a test/lab environment for SonicWALL similar to that of Cisco’s [Packet Tracer](http://www.packettracernetwork.com/)?  I’m trying to find a way to simulate some configuration changes without tampering with my production environment.

Answer (score 2):

The only one I managed to find was the
[Dell SonicWALL GMS Demo](https://gms.demo.sonicwall.com/sgms/auth).

Comment: This is also the only one that I know of - unfortunately, it lacks a lot of the functionality that Cisco's Packet Tracer has - namely, you can set up a rule in the demo, but you can't send fake traffic to it and watch it be redirected/blocked etc.

Also, for a more general link to live SonicWALL demos (including the ability to work with one specific device instead of the management system), check out this link: http://livedemo.sonicwall.com/